# Sudo with auth sufficient pam_tid.so does not work with tmux

Tags: mac, sudo, tmux

I did not really like the idea of installing some third-party sudo tool, so instead of using sudo-touchid I decided to use the /etc/pam.d/sudo trick and it works wonders. I use iTerm2 with zsh, and with that setup it works correctly. But when I use tmux (with reattach-to-user-namespace default command) sudo always asks for a password. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What is `/etc/pam.d/sudo` trick ?

Comment: Adding `auth sufficient pam_tid.so` to the top of `/etc/pam.d/sudo`.

Comment: @Alex https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306324/263848

Comment: @JBis Thank you for the link, actually I know this "trick", I just tried to give a clue to OP to update his question to avoid been downvoted for low quality question and use more descriptive steps instead of using word "tricks" which is kinda punishable on this site.

Comment: @Alex Ah. Maybe it'll help someone else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I experienced the same issues. Surprisingly, Touch ID does work in Apple's GNU screen distribution and after looking at its implementation, it seems like `screen` attaches to the user's per-session namespace instead of the per-user namespace.

The following patches port this approach to `tmux` and `reattach-to-user-namespace` and fix the issue for me:

1. https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/pull/70
2. https://github.com/tmux/tmux/pull/1434

**EDIT:** Since these patches caused some technical issues (as explained in the pull request), I instead solved the problem using a custom PAM module to reattach to the user's per-session namespace before running the `pam_tid` module: https://github.com/fabianishere/pam_reattach

Comment: I can attest that pam_reattach is a great solution and it can even be installed via `brew` so you can track the changes you've made to your system more easily.

Answer (score 2):

```
brew install pam-reattach
```

Then use this sudo wrapper to automatically add the necessary config (needed because macOS resets the config on updates)(beware that if this corrupts your settings you’ll be in a rough patch, so perhaps just manually editing the file and verifying it immediately might be better):

```bash
sudo () {
    unset -f sudo
    if [[ "$(uname)" == 'Darwin' ]]
    then
        if ! command grep 'pam_tid.so' /etc/pam.d/sudo --silent
        then
            command sudo sed -i -e '1s;^;auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so\n;' /etc/pam.d/sudo
        fi
        if ! command grep 'pam_reattach.so' /etc/pam.d/sudo --silent
        then
            command sudo sed -i -e '1s;^;auth     optional     pam_reattach.so\n;' /etc/pam.d/sudo
        fi
    fi
    command sudo "$@"
}
```

Comment: There is an ansible playbook task to automate this over here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259093/can-touch-id-for-the-mac-touch-bar-authenticate-sudo-users-and-admin-privileges

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the `pam_reattach` module from https://github.com/fabianishere/pam_reattach/tree/master as described in earlier answers.

```
    brew install pam_reattach
```

The one caveat is that in this day of M1+ Macs, `brew` installs the module in `/opt/homebrew/lib/pam/` instead of the default location of `/usr/lib/pam`. So the entries in `/etc/pam.d/sudo` need to include the full path to `pam_reattach.so`:

```
auth       optional       /opt/homebrew/lib/pam/pam_reattach.so
auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so
```

If you don't have the correct path to `pam_reattach.so` it is possible to get locked out of `sudo`. If that does happen, the trick is to open `/etc/pam.d` via `Finder` - `open /etc/pam.d` - click the lock icon and then *temporarily* allow edit permissions to `/etc/pam.d/sudo` so that any errors can be fixed.